# How to find the most recently updated file and change the file name into a standard one?

Tags: excel, vba

We have a daily report sending to a folder. The next day, our coordinator generates a summary by data query connecting the most recently updated file into the master file.

The file has a time stamp. We could not find a way to incorporate the time stamp into the Excel built-in data query.

I'm using Excel VBA to find the most recently updated report and change the file name into a standard name.

```
Sub ChangeName()

    Dim folderPath As String, tableName As String, latestTblName As String
    Dim latestModified As Date, modifiedDate As Date
    folderPath = " F:\Purchasing\Supply Chain Reports\IMAP Reports\"
    tableName = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")

    Do While tableName <> vbNullString
        modifiedDate = FileDateTime(folderPath & tableName)
        If latestModified < modifiedDate Then
            latestModified = modifiedDate
            latestTblName = tableName
        End If
        tableName = Dir()
    Loop
    Workbooks.Open folderPath & latestTblName
    Rows("0:6").Delete
    Kill "F:\Purchasing\Supply Chain Reports\IMAP Reports\ InvoiceQueryReport.xlsx"
    Dim thisWb As Workbook
    Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
    MyOldName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    MyNewName = "InvoiceQueryReport.xlsx" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="F:\Purchasing\Supply Chain Reports\IMAP Reports\" & MyNewName
    Kill MyOldName

End Sub
```

I had an error in the `TableName`, also when it saved, the master file was saved as the standard name, instead of the report.

Comment: Just a note: `MyNewName = "InvoiceQueryReport.xlsx" & ActiveWorkbook.Name` - isn't the extension in the wrong place?

Comment: Also - there is no row 0. `Rows("0:6").Delete` - that should be 1.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for your reply! lol, I messed up with Python in the row 0. Just wondering what would be the correct place for the extension... :)

Comment: At the end - concatenate it, e.g. `"InvoiceQueryReport" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".xlsx"`. Note - depending on your settings, the extension may or may not be included already in `ActiveWorkbook.Name`.